# Can we compare two dump file(xml) taken by uiautomatorviewer

Tags: android, ui-automation, ui-testing

I am using uiautomatorviewer tool of Android API Level 17, so I want to compare two dump file which is taken by uiautomatorviewer tool for UI Testing.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to open two different uiautomatorviewers. You could always save your UIXML to a local file and compare 2 saved UI's.